# concatenation in files

Tags: ruby, file

```
files = ["message_21.txt", "message_10.txt", "message_27.txt", "message_22.txt", "message_23.txt", "message_15.txt", "message_4.txt", "message_16.txt", "message_24.txt", "message_13.txt", "message_1.txt", "message_3.txt", "message_17.txt", "message_12.txt", "message_2.txt", "message_19.txt", "message_18.txt", "message_14.txt", "message_25.txt", "message_9.txt", "message_8.txt", "message_5.txt", "message_26.txt", "message_11.txt", "message_7.txt", "message_20.txt", "message_6.txt", "message_28.txt"]

def check_StubHub(file)
foo = File.open(PATH + "/" + file, 'r').read
foo.index(/StubHub/) ? true : false
end

def check_Ticketmaster(file)
foo = File.open(PATH + "/" + file, 'r').read
foo.index(/Ticketmaster/) ? true : false
end

@count = 0
files.each do |f|
@count = @count + 1
puts "Processing: " + f 

if check_StubHub(f)
    file = File.new(PATH + "/" + f, "r")

    while (line = file.gets)
        line = line.strip
            @event = line if line.match(/^Event/)
            @venue = line if line.match(/^Venue/)
            @date =  line if line.match(/^Date/)
        found = true if line.match(/^Date/)
        break if found
    end
 p @event,@venue,@date
    file.close

end

if check_Ticketmaster(f)
    @found = false
    file = File.new(PATH + "/" + f, "r")
    while (line = file.gets)
         @found=true if line =~ /You purchased/
         next unless @found
         puts line
         break if line =~ /Order for/
    end
    file.close

end
 File.open("/home/spritle/Desktop/vino-tryouts/fomo_r/specific_terms/terms.txt", 'w') do |f|
   f.puts @event,@venue,@date
  end
 end
```

In terminal i am getting

```
Processing: message_21.txt
Processing: message_10.txt
Processing: message_27.txt
"Event:    NBA Eastern Conference Semifinals Tickets: Orlando Magic at Boston Celtics - Home Game 1"
"Venue:    TD Banknorth Garden , Boston, MA"
"Date:    05-04-2009 08:00 PM EST"
Processing: message_22.txt
"Event:    Los Angeles Clippers at Boston Celtics Tickets"
"Venue:    TD Garden , Boston, MA"
"Date:    01-25-2010 07:30 PM EST"
Processing: message_23.txt
"Event:    Los Angeles Clippers at Boston Celtics Tickets"
"Venue:    TD Garden , Boston, MA"
"Date:    01-25-2010 07:30 PM EST"
Processing: message_15.txt
Processing: message_4.txt
You purchased 2 tickets to: 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ 
The Temper Trap
Webster Hall, New York, NY
Fri, Apr 2, 2010 07:00 PM 

Order for: Vikas Sekhri
Processing: message_16.txt
Processing: message_24.txt
"Event:    NBA Eastern Conference Semifinals Tickets: Orlando Magic at Boston Celtics - Home Game 3 (Game #5)"
"Venue:    TD Banknorth Garden , Boston, MA"
"Date:    05-12-2009 08:00 PM EST"
Processing: message_13.txt
You purchased 1 ticket to: 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ 
XPN Welcomes TV On The Radio, Celebration, and Saturn Never Sleeps
The Electric Factory, Philadelphia, PA
Fri, Apr 8, 2011 08:30 PM  

Order for: vikas sekhri
Processing: message_1.txt
Processing: message_3.txt
Processing: message_17.txt
Processing: message_12.txt
You purchased 4 tickets to: 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ 
O.A.R.
Bank of America Pavilion, Boston, MA
Thu, Jul 29, 2010 07:00 PM 

Order for: Vikas Sekhri
Processing: message_2.txt
Processing: message_19.txt
You purchased 1 ticket to: 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ 
XPN Welcomes TV On The Radio, Celebration, and Saturn Never Sleeps
The Electric Factory, Philadelphia, PA
Fri, Apr 8, 2011 08:30 PM  

Order for: vikas sekhri
Processing: message_18.txt
Processing: message_14.txt
Processing: message_25.txt
"Event:    NBA Eastern Conference Semifinals Tickets: Orlando Magic at Boston Celtics - Home Game 3 (Game #5)"
"Venue:    TD Banknorth Garden , Boston, MA"
"Date:    05-12-2009 08:00 PM EST"
Processing: message_9.txt
You purchased 2 tickets to: 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ 
Broken Bells with The Morning Benders
Royale Boston, Boston, MA
Fri, Jun 4, 2010 05:30 PM 

Order for: Vikas Sekhri
Processing: message_8.txt
Processing: message_5.txt
You purchased 2 tickets to: 
____________________________________________________________________________
_________________ 
The Temper Trap
Webster Hall, New York, NY
Fri, Apr 2, 2010 07:00 PM 

Order for: Vikas Sekhri
Processing: message_26.txt
"Event:    NBA Eastern Conference Semifinals Tickets: Orlando Magic at Boston Celtics - Home Game 1"
"Venue:    TD Banknorth Garden , Boston, MA"
"Date:    05-04-2009 08:00 PM EST"
Processing: message_11.txt
Processing: message_7.txt
You purchased 2 tickets to: 
____________________________________________________________________________
_________________ 
The Temper Trap
Webster Hall, New York, NY
Fri, Apr 2, 2010 07:00 PM 

Order for: Vikas Sekhri
Processing: message_20.txt
"Event:    NBA Eastern Conference Semifinals Tickets: Orlando Magic at Boston Celtics - Home Game 1"
"Venue:    TD Banknorth Garden , Boston, MA"
"Date:    05-04-2009 08:00 PM EST"
Processing: message_6.txt
You purchased 2 tickets to: 
____________________________________________________________________________
_________________ 
The Temper Trap
Webster Hall, New York, NY
Fri, Apr 2, 2010 07:00 PM 

Order for: Vikas Sekhri
Processing: message_28.txt
"Event:    NBA Eastern Conference Semifinals Tickets: Orlando Magic at Boston Celtics - Home Game 1"
"Venue:    TD Banknorth Garden , Boston, MA"
"Date: Tue, Apr 28, 2009 at 3:01 PM"
```

But in the file written i am getting the last puts only. File delete the previous information and showing last one only. I want to show all the information returned in @event, @venue, @date in file. I don't know how to do join the previous message with current message. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each @event, @venue, and @data holds one piece of data. You seem to be overwriting the values before saving them to the file. Try
putting a

```
puts "Writing to file"
```

Right before the f.puts line.

You'll likely see that it's happening after all the other processing happened. You want to print each time you update the 3 values.

I'd open up the output file at the beginning of your script, and either pass it in or set it to an instance variable (@file). Then every time you do a puts also do a @file.puts.

You could also make @event,... be arrays and instead of assigning to them do something like so:

```
#initialization
@output = []
#...
@output.push(line) if line.match(/^Event/)
@output.push(line) if line.match(/^Date/)
```

Then print out @events at the end.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
files = ["message_21.txt", "message_10.txt", "message_27.txt", "message_22.txt", "message_23.txt", "message_15.txt", "message_4.txt", "message_16.txt", "message_24.txt", "message_13.txt", "message_1.txt", "message_3.txt", "message_17.txt", "message_12.txt", "message_2.txt", "message_19.txt", "message_18.txt", "message_14.txt", "message_25.txt", "message_9.txt", "message_8.txt", "message_5.txt", "message_26.txt", "message_11.txt", "message_7.txt", "message_20.txt", "message_6.txt", "message_28.txt"]

def check_StubHub(file)
  foo = File.open(PATH + "/" + file, 'r').read
  foo.index(/StubHub/) ? true : false
end

def check_Ticketmaster(file)
  foo = File.open(PATH + "/" + file, 'r').read
  foo.index(/Ticketmaster/) ? true : false
end

@count = 0
files.each do |f|
  @count = @count + 1
  puts "Processing: " + f 

  if check_StubHub(f)
      file = File.new(PATH + "/" + f, "r")

      while (line = file.gets)
          line = line.strip
            @event = line if line.match(/^Event/)
            @venue = line if line.match(/^Venue/)
            @date =  line if line.match(/^Date/)
        found = true if line.match(/^Date/)
        break if found
      end
      puts @event,@venue,@date
      f.puts @event,@venue,@date
      file.close

  end

  if check_Ticketmaster(f)
      @found = false
      file = File.new(PATH + "/" + f, "r")
      while (line = file.gets)
         @found=true if line =~ /You purchased/
         next unless @found
         f.puts line
         puts line
         break if line =~ /Order for/
      end
      file.close

  end
  File.open("/home/spritle/Desktop/vino-tryouts/fomo_r/specific_terms/terms.txt", 'w') do |f|
   puts @event,@venue,@date
   f.puts @event,@venue,@date
  end
end
```

Comment: for puts @event,@venue,@date this
I am getting

Event:    NBA Eastern Conference Semifinals Tickets: Orlando Magic at Boston Celtics - Home Game 1
Venue:    TD Banknorth Garden , Boston, MA
Date:    05-04-2009 08:00 PM EST
Processing: message_28.txt
Event:    NBA Eastern Conference Semifinals Tickets: Orlando Magic at Boston Celtics - Home Game 1
Venue:    TD Banknorth Garden , Boston, MA
Date: Tue, Apr 28, 2009 at 3:01 PM

Comment: Do you want the to be comma delimited instead of pasted on 3 different lines?

Comment: for puts i am getting 2 set of results but for f.puts i am getting only one (last result)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem. Which output do you desire?

Answer (score 0):

Yo have wrong open mode for your file

```
 File.open("YOUR_PATH_TO_FILE", 'w') do |f|
   f.puts @event,@venue,@date
 end
```

if you check [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) you'll see

```
"w"  |  Write-only, truncates existing file
     |  to zero length or creates a new file for writing.
```

you need `a+` or one of

```
Mode |  Meaning
-----+--------------------------------------------------------
"a"  |  Write-only, starts at end of file if file exists,
     |  otherwise creates a new file for writing.
-----+--------------------------------------------------------
"a+" |  Read-write, starts at end of file if file exists,
     |  otherwise creates a new file for reading and
     |  writing.
```